# What does \l mean in /etc/issue?

Tags: debian

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l
```

`\l` does not seem to mean carriage return and newline here.

What does `\l` mean in `/etc/issue`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The escapes in `/etc/issue` are `getty` escapes, not the typical C-style or shell-style escapes. In particular:

- `\n` inserts the hostname (“nodename”)
- `\l` inserts the tty line

With the default `/etc/issue` you have, you’ll see

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8 hostname tty1
```

or something similar.

The available escape sequences are documented in the [`agetty(8)` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/agetty.8.html#ISSUE_FILES) (amongst others). If you want to use other escape sequences, you should check which `getty` implementation you’re using and read its documentation — some implementations support more escapes than others. `\n` and `\l` are widely supported.