# How to get the current terminal ID

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tty

Related: [How to get the current terminal name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77796/how-to-get-the-current-terminal-name)

But I only want the ID of the current terminal, e.g. when `tty` returns `/dev/pts/11` I only want to print `11`.

The idea is to add this information in the shell prompt after the username `\u` in the `PS1` variable in my `.bashrc` file:

Wanted result: `username11@localhost:~$`

For the moment I have:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u$(tty)@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

which gives: `username/dev/pts/11@localhost:~$`

Comment: try `$(basename $(tty))` can't test, thus can't post as answer.

Comment: @Archemar that does in fact work.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do have curiosity: may I ask _why_ you desire such an unusual prompt? What's your use case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `\l`, it gives [the basename of the shell’s terminal device name](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html):

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\l@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

This is similar to [the `\l` `getty` escape](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349938/86440).